# Нижние подчеркивания между буквами

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.example {
    text-underline-position: under;
    text-decoration: initial!important;
    text-underline-position: under;
}
```

```html
<a class="example" href =#> ССЫЛКА </a>
```

Всем привет! выплыло непонятное свойство, которое заключается в выделении текста ссылки нижним подчеркиванием, при этом, отключить его никак не могу. Кто с таким сталкивался? Хелп. на скрине свойства и проявление на фронте. (линии между буквами)  При наведении лииния исчезает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите достаточно полный код, демонстрирующий проблему

Comment: @andreymal добавил код, но смысл? ссылка работает обычно, просто у меня странное проявление. text-decoration: none; не помогает

Comment: `a:hover { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: @KolyaCherevan если странное проявление невозможно воспроизвести, значит его не существует и помочь никак не получится.

Comment: @MoloF при ховере исчезает эта линия сама по себе, но она не связана с text-decoration!

Comment: @KolyaCherevan может там псевдоэлемент ? Код предоставьте, если там не `text-decoration` то там `::after`  или `::before`

Comment: @MoloF никаких псевдоэлементов, тупо див

Answer (score -1):

**ВСЕМ СПАСИБО ЗА ПОМОЩЬ**, на этот елемент распространялось свойство *text-decoration: underline* от родителя, а именно от ссылки, в который был обернут div. НА будущее, если кто с таким столкнется, смотрите на родительские элементы, вдруг на них есть свойство text-decoration